# Is Foreach loop a definite or indefinite?

Tags: loops, foreach

Is Foreach loop a definite or indefinite one? Meaning do I know prior to the execution of the loop the number of iterations it is going to do?

Comment: Huh?  What language and context are you talking about?

Comment: The answer would be "it depends on the condition and the content" for all programming languages with for-loops that i know

Comment: I'm talking about any programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `foreach` in most languages ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java)) doesn't know beforehand how many iteration it will have to do. You could even use `foreach` to go through an infinite sequence.
That's why `for` exists

Answer (score 2):

In most languages a foreach loop will iterate over a collection of elements until the collection ends. In most languages I can think of a collection can be a definitive set of elements contained in memory OR a calculated set of elements that could in theory be of an infinite length. This would make the foreach loop "indefinite" in most modern languages.